# How to validate an XPS document?

Tags: c#, .net, xps

Is there any C# API to validate a generated XPS document?
(i.e. to make sure the file is a valid xps file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know about an API, but there is a Microsoft tool that tests a file's conformity to the XML Paper Specification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348104.aspx

Cheers!

Comment: and the C# program can call the tool and parse the output.

Comment: The linked page explains how to use the `isXPS.exe` tool but unfortunately the link to the download leads to a dead end. However, the tool is included in the Windows SDK. I found mine here: `<Program Files>\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\IsXps.exe`.

Answer (score -3):

Xps just an XML format.

You could try:

1. Rename the XPS file to *.zip, and
   unzip it.  You will see all the xml.
   There are quite a few files and
   directories.
2. Download the XML Paper Specification for xps from
   http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/print/xps/xpsspec.mspx.
3. So now you have the
   spec for xps, the schemas (there are five),
   and a whole bunch of xml documents
   to validate.

There are of course plenty of easy ways to validate xml in C# once you figure out which schema corresponds to which xml file.

Good luck with that.

Comment: Actually I think it's a Packaging file format. Which also means it's a 'known' structure of XML files inside a ZIP file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371623(v=vs.85).aspx